# Is it ok to have facebook and twitter as authentication for an e-commerce site?

Tags: authentication, e-commerce

I have been looking around and noticed that ecommerce sites are not using social auth and i am building an ecommerce site and wanted to know the reasons for not using social auth.

Comment: Honestly, this just pisses off! This question is precise, people with e-commerce web development best practices and PCI compliance experience can answer this. Take a look at the answers. This is type of behavior that is ruining this community and is why many users are becoming very frustrated with Stackoverflow. Hopefully Stackoverflow has  performance reviews for its moderators because this guy is found wanting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, will you be storing credit card details? You might hit some problems with PCI compliance if purchases can be made through social network logins.

If you're just using it as a useful way of signing up, you should be OK.

Comment: I would't  store them, thinking of using the Stripe api, even if i dont do social auth, i will not store the details. Since this is my first e-commerce site i am building, i am not sure if that means the person will have to re-enter their credit card details each time.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent survey my employer conducted, we established that in younger (<30 years)  users there was a perception that they did not want to link financial data with there social networking data due to, primarily, a lower level of trust in social networking brands, w.r.t visa et. al

Answer (score 0):

I would never trust any site that allows me to login with my Facebook account. Too much risk for getting my user and password sniffed out and abused.

Comment: As a developer you may have this fear due to your technical knowledge but we know that the general public don't mind and see it as a convenience.